# Unable to use jQuery click function on markup between ::before and ::after

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been having a lot of trouble doing this.  I'm trying to create a jQuery click function when clicking on an addToCart button but the addToCart button is inbetween ::before and ::after in the markup.  I'm always able to do this but I'm finding that if I'm trying to create a click function between ::before and ::after, then I never can get any jQuery click functions to work.

Here is an example that should work but doesn't:

```
jQuery("body").on("click", "div.product-buttons a", function () {
    console.log("button clicked");
});
```

Here is the markup:

```
::before

<div class="product-buttons">
<a class="btn occ-lenox-button" data-bind="text: $parent.translate('btn-   add-to-cart'), css: {'disabled': $parent.quickView.isAddToCartClicked}, click: $parent.quickView.quickAddToCart">ADD TO CART</a>
</div>

::after
```

Comment: `inbetween ::before and ::after in the markup` can you be more specific?

Comment: click on the link and inspect the addTocart button markup and you'll see the markup inbetween the ::before and ::after

Comment: What if I don't wanna? When asking a question, you are supposed to add a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Chances are that by tomorrow that problem would be fixed and your question will be of no use to anybody else who comes in when they don't have the proper context.

Comment: ok, i'll update my question and get rid of the hyperlink.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wich version of jQuery are u using?

Method on was introduced in jQuery version 1.7.

I think you have to upgrade your jQuery library to the newest version.

Otherwise, you can use bind:

```
$(".product-buttons a").bind( "click", function(e) {
    // your code
    e.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for responding but I tried your code and got the following error: `VM12772:2 ERROR: Execution of script 'lenox' failed! $ is not defined`  I needed use an inline wait function to wait for jQuery to load.

Comment: jQuery version 2.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Racking my brain on this and got some advice.  This finally works.  I had to wait for jQuery to load:

```
(function defer() {
    if (window.jQuery) {
        jQuery("body").on("click", "div.product-buttons", function () {
            console.log("button clicked");
         });
    } else {
        setTimeout(function() { defer();}, 50);
    }
})();
```